# How do I see the data type for each of my table's columns

Tags: matlab, types

For example:

```
>> temp = table([1; 2], {'a'; 'b'});

temp = 

    Var1    Var2
    ____    ____

    1       'a' 
    2       'b'
```

Is there a way to find out what data types are in each column of this table? Does it also matter to the data types whether I used an array to create the first column and a cell array to create the second column?

**EDIT:** I am actually looking for a function that would accept `temp` as an input and return some sort of array containing the column types, for example:

```
>> columnType(temp)

ans = {'double' 'cell'}
```

While it is very good to know that `class(temp.Var1)` returns the column type of the first column of `temp`, it becomes tedious when the table has many columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  Use [`class`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/class.html) on each of the table variables to see what they look like:

```
>> temp = table([1; 2], {'a'; 'b'})

temp = 

    Var1    Var2
    ____    ____

    1       'a' 
    2       'b' 

>> class(temp.Var1)

ans =

double

>> class(temp.Var2)

ans =

cell
```

The second data type makes sense because `cell` arrays are designed to be containers that can store any type in each slot.  You would think that you would get `char` as every element in your cell array is a `char` type, but the bigger picture is that you used a `cell` array to initialize the second column.

If you decided to use purely characters, specifically removing the `{}` braces, we get this:

```
>> temp = table([1; 2], ['a';'b'])

temp = 

    Var1    Var2
    ____    ____

    1       a   
    2       b   

>> class(temp.Var1)

ans =

double

>> class(temp.Var2)

ans =

char
```

To answer your second question, no it doesn't matter what data type goes in each column.... as long as each column has **the same data type**.  You could have characters in one column, doubles in another, a cell array in another, `uint8`s in another and so on.

---

If you'd like to automate this and not manually check the class per variable, use [`varfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varfun.html) and apply a function to each variable in your table:

```
>> varfun(@class, temp, 'OutputFormat', 'cell')

ans = 

    'double'    'cell'
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have edited my question as I do not want to havve to manually inspect each column. Would you suggest passing the `class` function to some sort of `cellfun` function?

Comment: I have another question. So we have determined that my `temp.Var2` is a cell. Yet, when I type `temp.Var2` in the matlab command window it returns an `ans` that looks like an array. Why would this happen?

Comment: @Alex - That's just the way MATLAB is displaying the variable.  Look at your workspace and see for yourself that it's a cell.

Comment: Let me know if you have any more questions... and thanks for the accept!